# Why don't the images fully display when I convert HTML to PDF with Perl's HTML::HTMLDoc?

Tags: html, perl, pdf

I need to create a PDF file from the HTML I have created usign rrdcgi. This page contains the details and graphs in PNG format. I have written the below code using Perl module [HTML::HTMLDoc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-HTMLDoc) to create a PDF file using saved HTML file. The images are of size width 1048 and hight 266 but when creating a PDF file the images are not shown completly from the right side.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::HTMLDoc;

my $filename = shift;
my $htmldoc = new HTML::HTMLDoc();

$htmldoc->set_input_file($filename);
$htmldoc->no_links();
$htmldoc->landscape();
$htmldoc->set_jpeg_compression('50');
$htmldoc->best_image_quality();
$htmldoc->color_on();
$htmldoc->set_right_margin('1', 'mm');
$htmldoc->set_left_margin('1', 'mm');
$htmldoc->set_bodycolor('#FFFFFF');
$htmldoc->set_browserwidth('1000');
my $pdf = $htmldoc->generate_pdf();
$pdf->to_file('foo.pdf');
```

I need help on following items:

How do I display the complete image on page.

Any help with the Perl code would be really appreciated.

Comment: You've got two distinct questions there.

Comment: I have edited my question for single query.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to [HTML::HTMLDoc documentation](http://tinyurl.com/9h6y2t):

> **set_browserwidth($width)**
>
> specifies the browser width in pixels.
>   The browser width is used to scale
>   images and pixel measurements when
>   generating PostScript and PDF files.
>   It does not affect the font size of
>   text. The default browser width is 680
>   pixels which corresponds roughly to a
>   96 DPI display.
>
> **Please note that
>   your images and table sizes are equal
>   to or smaller than the browser width,
>   or your output will overlap or
>   truncate in places**.

You said that images are 1048 width but you specified 1000 on browser width using:

```
$htmldoc->set_browserwidth('1000');
```

try to increase browserwidth parameter to fit your images.